# Is Big Query an append-only option?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

we need an append-only database for sensitive records due to some compliant laws. Looking online I've seen the following statement

> Data in BigQuery is immutable. i.e. data once written is not modified. Whenever a change happens, a new version of the data is written.

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/backup-disaster-recovery-strategies-bigquery)

However I've not been able to find a way to prove that in fact after a record has mutated (Updated or deleted) there is a new version of the table, I've checked the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` metadata, and all the logs generated in cloud logging after updating a record, but I can not find something like an ID that will show that after a change in the table, a new version is generated

Is there something that I'm not seeing? and if not, is there a GCP product that could be audited as append-only? Thanks!

Comment: You can do that by controling the permission to BigQuery but it's not a built in feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for a "ledger database" not a DataWarehouse. BigQuery does not comply with your needs.

When the docs says that data in BigQuery is immutable it means that you cannot in fact update a record, but will instead recreate entire blocks of data. This is the case for RedShift too and maybe others cloud DataWarehouses.

So the answer is definetely **no**. BigQuery does not fit your needs in this case.

I would suggest you look at [Amazon QLDB](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/qldb/) to check if it fit your needs. Also found that [SQL Server on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/ledger/ledger-overview?view=sql-server-ver16) has some ledger capabilities which might be worth looking for and there is also a [Confidential Ledger](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/azure-confidential-ledger) service.